# @RabbitListener is not working with queue names pattern

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, amqp

Me using spring boot for my project where i need to listen few queues at run time with pattern enables in rabbitlister.

i have tried `@RabbitListener(queues="queue*")`.

but i throws exception with constant should be used in queue name.

Any help would be appreciated .

And also i have query with json convertor in spring boot rabbitmq:

```
@Bean
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter,Queue notificationQueue) {
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
        container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        container.setQueueNames(notificationQueue.getName());
        container.setMessageListener(listenerAdapter);
        return container;
    }   

    @Bean
    Reciver receiver() {
        return new Reciver ();
    }

    @Bean
    MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter(Reciver receiver) {
        return new MessageListenerAdapter(receiver,"receiveMethod");
    }
```

And IN Reciever

```
receiveMethod(Message msg){

//Code
}
```

Here i get exception says that

```
org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.exception.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Failed to invoke target method 'onMessage' with argument type = [class [B], value = [{[B@4ed663ad}]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter.invokeListenerMethod(MessageListenerAdapter.java:408) ~[spring-rabbit-1.5.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessageListenerAdapter.java:298) ~[spring-rabbit-1.5.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:757) ~[spring-rabbit-1.5.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:680) ~[spring-rabbit-1.5.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$001(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:93) [spring-rabbit-1.5.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$1.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:183) ~[spring-rabbit-1.5.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1358) [spring-rabbit-1.5.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:661) ~[spring-rabbit-1.5.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1102) [spring-rabbit-1.5.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1086) [spring-rabbit-1.5.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$1100(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:93) [spring-rabbit-1.5.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1203) [spring-rabbit-1.5.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_77]
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.mdm.amqp.MDMNotificationListener.onMessage([B)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at org.springframework.util.MethodInvoker.prepare(MethodInvoker.java:174) ~[spring-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter.invokeListenerMethod(MessageListenerAdapter.java:386) ~[spring-rabbit-1.5.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    ... 12 common frames omitted
```

Comment: @RabbitListener is not working with pattern in queue names

Comment: Can some one please help me by answering or suggesting the answer